# Induction coil interference from an electromagnet?

Tags: coil, induction, electromagnetic

If I have a nail three dividers on it to keep the coils on the nail, and wrap an induction coil between the head of the nail and the middle, then wrap an electromagnetic coil between the tip of the nail and the middle, would the electromagnetic coil interfere too much with the induction coil?  Would this turn into a transformer, or would the induction coil be able to still function?  The reason for this is I am looking to make guitar pickups, and have a bit of wire, but not many magnets.  I thought this may work, but I am unsure whether the electromagnetic coil would interfere too much.

Answer (score 1):

Both windings are just coils of wire -- giving them different names does not change how they function.

Yes, when wound on the same core, they will definitely interact with each other quite strongly. However, you need to decide whether that interaction works in your particular application.

I take it you want to put a DC current through one of the coils in order to provide a field similar to what a permanent magnet produces. That's fine -- the other coil will not pick up DC. However, any AC (noise) in that DC current will be coupled to the other coil, and it's possible that it will overwhelm the signal from the guitar strings that you're looking for.

So, how good are you at building low-noise DC current sources?